# Data Frame manipulation. Colapse by adding observation

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1 = structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A2"), class = "factor"), DAY = structure(c(1392647220, 1392733620, 
1392647220, 1392733620), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    P = c(10, 5, 100, 80)), .Names = c("ID", "DAY", "P"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

but with 50k observations

I want to collapse it to look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A1","A2"), TotalP=c(15,180))
```

What is the best way of doing this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(P ~ ID, data=df1, FUN=sum)
  ID   P
1 A1  15
2 A2 180
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(df1$P, list(ID = df1$ID), sum)
##   ID   x
## 1 A1  15
## 2 A2 180
```

There's also `by`.  We can use it with `stack`

```
> rev(stack(by(df1$P, df1$ID, sum)))
##   ind values
## 1  A1     15
## 2  A2    180
```

And there's always the ever-popular long-form version(s)

```
> W <- lapply(split(df1$P, df1$ID), sum)
> data.frame(ID = names(W), TotalP = unlist(W, use.names = FALSE))
##   ID TotalP
## 1 A1     15
## 2 A2    180
```